# What type of relationship is this and how to implement it in .NET Core (EFCore, FluentAPI)?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

The problem I have is pretty easy, but my mind stopped working. Sorry if my questions is dumb, but I'm not really good with databases (neither I am with EFCore).

I want to have the following tables:

**CVs: with ID and Name/Title (string)**

**Skills: with ID and Name/Title (string)**

**SkillsCV: with ID, CvID (foreign key to a record in CVs), SkillID (foreign key to a record in Skills)**

I don't want to have a foreign key to SkillsCV in the CVs and Skills tables. Is it possible? Is it possible in .NET Core and more importantly with Fluent API?
I've made a small research for FluentAPI and there are foreign keys in the both ends in one-to-one relationships. Is this needed? BTW, it is a one-to-one relationship, right? I don't want the one side to know about the other side. Is this what's called 0 to 1, or this is a completely different thing? I'm really confused.

So what I've seen for one-to-one relationships in FluentAPI, I need the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Skill>()
        .HasOne(skill => skill.SkillCV) // but I don't have a SkillCV object in Skill model
        .WithOne(skillCV => skillCV.Skill) // I have skillCV.Skill
        .HasForeignKey<SkillCV>(skillCV => skillCV.SkillID); // I have this foreign key in skillCV as well
```

But I don't want to have an object (or foreign key) in the Skills table (as I don't want such in the CVs table). **Is this possible?** I'm for sure doing something wrong. **Can you help me to find my mistake** (if there is one)?

If you know a better way to do this, please share it. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: A quick example to what I want to create:

**CVs Table:**

**ID, Name**

1 "CV1"

2 "CV2"

3 "CV3"

**Skills Table:**

**ID, Name**

1 "C#"

2 "Java"

3 "Python"

**SkillsCVs Table:**

**ID, CvID, SkillID**

1   1   1

2   1   3

3   2   1

Is this a good solution to solve this problem? I haven't created the SkillsCVs table yet, now I have only CVs and Skills (every skill has a CV_ID), but this way when I need to populate a select box in the frontend, I need to return DISTINCT Skills from the API (because there are 800 C# for example records for different CVs). I thought a SkillsCVs table will solve this issue, but I'm not entirely sure now :D

Comment: As I understand you don't want to take the column in any of the two tables, so the only solution I can think of is a third table in which you link the cv id with the skill id. It is the only way, is that what you need?

Comment: @Diego658 I want to have the 3 tables (at the top of my question): CVs, Skills, SkillsCV. So, I have the 3rd table with the 2 foreign keys to the other tables. I want to have a reference to Skills table in SkillsCV without having a SkillsCV reference in Skills. One really fast example: Skills table has the following records: 1 C#; 2 Java; 3 Python and in the CVs we have 1 CV1, 2 CV2, 3 CV3 - then I want to have SkillsCV with the following records: 1 CV1 1 (which is C#); 2 CV1 3 (which is Python); 3 CV2 1 (which is C#), etc....

Comment: Why do you say it is a one-to-one relationship? it seems to be like a M-to-N relationship between CVs and Skills, being SkillCVs the intermediate table for it.

Comment: Yes, it sounds a little like a many-to-many with the associative intermediate table. That's why I'm confused. But I have 1 CV with many skills. Let's say CV with ID 1 has the following skills C# (id 1) and Java (id 2). How to link CV with id1 to Skills with IDs 1 and 2. The skills are like an immutable list of seeded skills like the alphabet (you seed it once) and every CV has many Skills, but I don't want to have Skill1 for CV1; Skill1 for CV2. I want the skills to be "distinct" and not repeating. That's what I'm trying to do with the intermediate table.

Comment: Also, in EF you need to define a navigation property in one way at least to be able to navigate through the domain and query it.

Comment: I get your model now. So it's one CV to many CVSkills, one CVSkill to one Skill. But in your example you show Skill id 1 in two different CVs...

Comment: Then just have a Many to Many model. You can use the associative table to add the additional info you want for each case.

Comment: @PabloCG Thanks for the replies. I could explained it wrong yes. That's why I gave 1 more example. I'm really confused. I want to have 10 distinct skills that don't belong to anything and every CV to use many of these 10 skills. 1 CV -> many SkillsCVs -> 1 Skill.  Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a [many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) relationship. You could model things like this:

```cs
public class Skill
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
 }

 public class CV
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
 }

 public class SkillCV
 {
    public int SkillID { get; set; }

    public Skill Skill { get; set; }

    public int CVID { get; set; }

    public CV CV { get; set; }
 }
```

Then to set this up with Fluent API, you could do this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SkillCV>()
    .HasKey(t => new { t.SkillID, t.CVID});

modelBuilder.Entity<SkillCV>()
    .HasOne(pt => pt.Skill)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.SkillID);

modelBuilder.Entity<SkillCV>()
    .HasOne(pt => pt.CV)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.CVID);
```

This way your joins later will be simple, and the `SkillCV` table will have a composite key made up of `SkillID` and `CVID` (ensuring referential integrity).

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. I've used many times many-to-many, but I got really confused today, because I started it from one-to-many and my mind started brainstorming and I've got really confused. Thank you for the good example + the Fluent API code. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only with annotations if I understand you correctly.

```
 public class Skill
 {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
 public class Cv
 {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
 public class SkillCv
 {
    [ForeignKey("Skill")]
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Cv")]
    public int CvId { get; set; }

    public virtual Skill Skill{ get; set; }

    public virtual  Cv Cv { get; set; }
 }

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cv> Cvs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SkillCv> SkillCvs { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //The entity does not have its own key, only the relationship of the two
        modelBuilder.Entity<SkillCv>().HasNoKey();
    }

}
```

So you will have a row in the table for each skill that has a cv

```
var allSkillFromCv = await _context.SkillCvs.Where(s => s.CvId == 1).ToListAsync()
```

If you want to use the navigation property

```
var allSkillFromCv = await _context.SkillCvs.Where(s => s.CvId == 1).Include(s => s.Skill).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I think many-to-many was the solution. I figured it out with the help in the comments below my question. But I appreciate the detailed example you gave. Thank you. Is this an example for a Keyless Entity model? I've made something similar in the past but with a script migration.

Comment: Yes it is a keyless entity, but you should consider adding indexes to the columns as they will help you a lot with the speed of the queries when you have thousands of rows. The SkillCv entity is just a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You need three table here: CVs Table, Skills Table and SkillsCVs Table. You have a
 Many-to-Many relationship between CVs Table and Skills Table. You have to define the Many-to-Many relationship using Fluent API. you need navigation property in both CVs Table and Skills Table

```
public class CV
{
    .... 

    public IList<SkillCV> SkillsCVs { get; set; }
}
 public class Skill
 {
        .... 

        public IList<SkillCV> SkillsCVs { get; set; }
 }
```

in DB context

```
  public DbSet<SkillCV> SkillsCVs { get; set; }
```

You also need to define relationship using Fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SkillCV>()
    .HasOne<Skill>(sc => sc.Skill)
    .WithMany(s => s.SkillsCVs)
    .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.SkillID);


modelBuilder.Entity<SkillCV>()
    .HasOne<CV>(sc => sc.CV)
    .WithMany(s => s.SkillsCVs)
    .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.CvID);
```